# Is this Rose Rosette or just new growth?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, roses

So I am a new gardener, I just have gotten into it in the past three years or so and I finally got in my garden to look the way that I want it to! Obviously, it is a never ending work in progress, but it is my sanctuary and I love it! Recently, I learned about Rose Rosette when I found out that one of my roses was completely eaten up with it. I'm afraid that I am incredibly paranoid now and I'm seeing it everywhere and I'm going to rip all of my roses out in the process!! Can anyone help me determine if I need to get rid of these or if it is just normal new growth?! I'm so devastated, I love my roses!

These are the bushes I'm concerned about.. the bottom right is the one I pulled out

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Symptoms usually appear in July, not in June, and there's nothing there I'd be worried about at this stage. There's certainly no 'witches broom' appearance so far, so I'd be inclined to wait a bit and see what happens. It's not abnormal for new growth on roses to be red, so I'd advocate a 'wait and see' approach until you're sure its rose rosette. The mites which cause this overwinter on the bushes, and are carried passively by the wind as well as being transported by you unintentionally, but grubbing out every rose which produces new red growth is probably a bit of an over reaction right now.This link might be useful in helping you decide over time http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/diseases/viruses/rose-rosette.aspx

The only photo which shows something that might be odd is the final one, but it's not terribly clear - it looks almost as if there's lots of new growth which has been flattened or trampled in some way, and the rest of the plant is not visible for comparison purposes.

Comment: Danielle E., you said about the indistinct photo: "the bottom right is the one I pulled out" ... Do you mean you took out the entire bush? or just cut off the new red growth? That would explain why that photo looks wilted, but other than that (the wiltiness) none of those red shoots look any different from normal tender new spring growth on roses to me (admittedly an amateur).